# Empty span/div is not really empty

Tags: jquery, html

When I check the username and all goes fine the span with id user_error gets empty, but it doesn't go the same way when i check the email and it says that the span email_error is not empty. Why is this happening?

```
<form name="field" method="post" id="form">
    <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
    <input name="username" id="username" type="text"/>   
    <span id="user_error"></span><br><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input name="email" id="email" type="text"/>   
    <span id="email_error"></span><br><br>
    <input name="submit" type="button" value="Register" id="submit"/><br>    
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").blur(validateUser);
    $("#email").blur(validateEmail);
    $("#submit").click(submitForm);

    function validateUser() {
        var user = $("#username").val();
        var user_regex = /^([^\s])*$/;

        if($("#username").val().length == 0)
            $("#user_error").html("Insert username");
        else if($("#username").val().length > 14)                          
            $("#user_error").html("Username too long");         
        else if($("#username").val().length < 6)
            $("#user_error").html("Username too short");                
        else if (user_regex.test(user) == false)
            $("#user_error").html("Username no whitespaces");           
        else
            $("#user_error").html("");
    }       


    function validateEmail() {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var email_regex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;    

        if($("#email").val().length == 0)
            $("#email_error").html("Insert email");
        else if (email_regex.test(email) == false)
            $("#email_error").html("Email not valid");
        else
            $("#email_error").html(""); 
    }

    function submitForm() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();

        //if ($("#user_error").text().length){
        //alert ('ERROR!')  
        //}
        //else {
        //  alert ('OK!')   
        //}

        if ($("#email_error").text().length){
            alert ('ERROR!')    
        else
            alert ('OK!')               
    }
});
```

Comment: try to `console.log($("#email_error").text())` in submitForm function - what are you getting?

Comment: It would be nice if you clarified what you meant by "it says that the span email_error is not empty"?  Are you saying when you submit the form, you run into an issue, and you're seeing your `ERROR!` alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps because you're validating the fields on `blur`, but not on `submit`? Add this:

```
function submitForm() {
    $('#username,#email').trigger('blur');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/GndWV/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if ($("#email_error").text().length == 0)
```